# I Want To check if template match in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence

I Want to check template match is True Or False.

Just Something Like This:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
img2 = img.copy() 
template = cv.imread('template.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
methods = ['cv.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv.TM_CCORR',
            'cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']
for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)
    res = cv.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(res)

    if template_match:
        //do something
```

I had read this But I Dont Get It https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Thanks For Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the features of your template.

---

- > An image features, such as edges and interest points, provide rich information on the image content. [source](http://morpheo.inrialpes.fr/%7EBoyer/Teaching/Mosig/feature.pdf)

  ---
- For instance: if below is your template, then find its characteristic.

  [image]    [image]

  ```
   import numpy as np
   import imutils
   import glob
   import cv2

   template = cv2.imread("template.jpg")
   template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
   (h, w) = template.shape[:2]
  ```

2. Get the features of your image.

---

- [image]   [image]

3. Check if the template features are matching with the image features.

---

```py
result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
```

- `cv2.TM_CCOEFF` is just an option, you can use many other [templates](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)

4. Find the minimum and the maximum values of the `result` variable

---

```py
(_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
```

5. Now, you can check the template match is True Or False.

---

```
found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)
```

So, if the template is detected, the `found` variable returns with a tuple of length 3, which means yes the template is matched. For instance:

```py
(495.000, (148, 26), 1)
```

- 495.000 is the maximum value in the array.
- (148, 26) are starting `(x, y)` coordinates of the found object.
- 1.0 is the radius.

Comment: Glad, if I help :)